# Selective Dropdown menus in QGIS

Tags: fields-attributes, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.0.

So far I can create a dropdown menu but in the shown example I could still choose 'coins' in "type" and '5$' in "value" which is wrong.

Are there rules I can add to make the options in "value" dependent of the choice in "type"?

And if so, is there also an option which automatically fills out "type" with the correct value when "value" is filled out?

I seek a short example on how to set it up.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at QGIS 3.2 new feature: [Drill-down (cascading) forms](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.2.0/#drill-down-cascading-forms)