# QGIS Value Relation filter

Tags: qgis, expression, forms

Let's say I have 3 layers:

- point layer (columns: id, group),
- table layer named materials (columns: point_id, mat_id),
- table layer named mat_list (columns group, mat_id).

There is relation between point layer and materials table using id and point_id and value relation materials - mat_list.

In mat_list I grouped materials for example:

[image]

What I want to do is after I pick group in point layer it will limit choices to pick in materials layer.

EDIT:

More information maybe usefull

[image]

table/layer with material list

[image]

layer with points.

[image]

Relation between point and material.

[image]

In this screen I want to limit materials to group_2 so drop down list will show material_4, material_5, material_6. But group is picked in point layer not material. Is there any easy way to accomplish it.

Comment: that's called "cascading" or "drill-down" forms. http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.2.0/#drill-down-cascading-forms

Comment: There's an **unanswered** duplicate question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/287919/81764. So let's leave this question open.

Comment: I can do cascading in the same layer but I want to do cascading based on value in different layer and Im not sure how to access that value. I tryed function current_value but no with success.

Comment: You mentioned that there's a "relationship" between the two layers. Are the layers actually [joined](https://www.gislounge.com/working-with-tables-mastering-qgis/)? If not, do a table join according to the linked instructions. I'm not sure if the join is dynamically updated or not. If not, you might need to use a virtual field instead of using a table join. In either case, you should end up with the "group" field copied into the materials layer. Use the "group" field for your drill-down forms.