# Filtering a value relation selection box with an expresion when one column has string LIKE the other Column

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator

Oke I have setup two value relations between one polygon layer and two tables, this is to make the selection of multiple values possible. The first value relation is not really that important you just have a **multiple** selection of value's that is being the main-code. **Note xy are placeholders, because of privacy reasons I cannot just post these codes publicly.**

For example:

Main code: xy1, xy2, xy3, xy4

**Edit: 22/05/2020**

**New added detail: 
These are part of a multiple selection list. So one Object can have xy1 and xy2 for example.**

The second value relation is that basically that you have the main code, a subcode and a completed code that is composed of a merger of the main code and the subcode.
For example :

- Maincode: xy1
- Subcode : f
- Completed code: xy1f

This completed code is the one that is being selected but of course I want this selection to be filtered based on the main code. You may just ask ""why not just use another column being the subcode and then go futher from there?". That is because the subcode does not always appear in every main code.

**Edit 22/05/2020:
The selection of the subcode is also multiple choice.**
For example xy1 has subcodes a & b, but xy4 does not have subcode b.

[image: Example image]

The problem is I do not exactly know how to refer to the polygon layer itself in the field calculator. Not to mention since you have multiple value's being selected in that column so I kind of know you have to a LIKE 'maincode polygon layer' command but so far I can only refer to the table not the polygon layer table.

Comment: What is it you exactly want to do. Cause working with field calculator will edit the attributes in your atrribute tabel. If you want to filter you can right click on polygon in the layers panel and choose filter.

Comment: I want to filter what I can select out of the multiple values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the cascading form function has been available since [QGIS 3.2](https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.2.0/#drill-down-cascading-forms) but [past](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287919/selective-dropdown-menus-in-qgis-3-0) [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321137/qgis-value-relation-filter) have never really elaborated on this, so if you weren't able to follow the video in the QGIS changelog link above, here is how it works.

Assume you have two tables, `main_code` and `sub_codes`, as below. `main_code` only has the main values and `sub_codes` has an entry for each combination of main and sub code.

[image]

Now go to Properties > Forms for your polygon layer, which has a field for the main code (`main_poly`) and a field for the completed code (`comp_poly`).

Set up a value relation for your `main_poly`, using the `main_code` table values.

[image]

Now set up a value relation for `comp_poly`.

You want the values to be the `completed` column from `sub_codes` table, so select that for your key value column.

However you want available values to be filtered by the `maincodes` column - if it matches the current value of `main_poly` in the feature being digitised.

This can be described with the following expression:

```
"maincode"=current_value('main_poly')
```

Or, if your `sub_codes` table *only* has a `completed` column and you want to use a LIKE expression,

```
"completed" ilike current_value('main_poly')||'%'
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

If you want to match multiple selections, this is much easier if you have a `maincode` column in your `sub_codes` table.

Use the following expression:

```
current_value('main_poly') ilike '%'||"maincode"||'%'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I did as you instructed the problem is when, I check a choice at Maincode (in my project is called "Hoofdcode" all choices off sub code become invisible. This can be solved by putting main code only on one choice but both have to be multiple choice to work.

Comment: Which expression did you try, the `=` one or the `ILIKE` one?

Comment: I tried both same problem when the Main code is set to multiple choice.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean allowing multiple selections? This was not clear from your original post, I would recommend adding that detail in.

Comment: I now did, but thank you anyway this solution does kind of work for something I have where there is indeed only one choice to be had. If you know the solution of this problem specificity please let me know.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a possible solution, could you check if this is what you were after? Note that the results will end up formatted rather oddly like {"xy1a","xy2a"} etc. so you may need to do some data cleaning when exporting to other formats.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. The list and data format then I get at the end seems to be fine for now. If I ever get anymore problems. I will ask again here. Thank you again